# The relevance of i = -1 in a piece of code

Tags: java, for-loop, bubble-sort

I was studying a piece of code and I came across "`i = -1`" and I could not figure out its significance in the scenario.

The point of the code is to sort the array from smallest to largest and find the difference between the largest and smallest numbers.

```
public int bigDiff(int[] nums) {
  int answer = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; i++){
    if (nums[i] > nums[i + 1]){
      int temp = nums[i];
      nums[i] = nums[i + 1];
      nums[i + 1] = temp;
      i = -1;
    }
  }
  return (nums[nums.length - 1] - nums[0]);

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It restarts the loop over from the beginning of the array.

Comment: It gets i to -1 then i++ gets executed so i becomes 0 again, meaning it starts from beginning.

Comment: Note that this looks like an implementation of bubble sort, which is widely known as an inefficient algorithm.

Comment: Perhaps this goes without saying, but the algorithm is very inefficient. It's using Bubble Sort just to subtract the largest element from the smallest element in the array.

Comment: I find it questionable to modify the loop index variable like that.

Comment: It sets `i` to `-1`. What happens when you set `i` to `-1` in that code? That shouldn't be that hard to figure out - just step through the code line-by-line and see what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a implementation of bubble sort. `i=-1;` resets the loop to the beginning if it finds that something isn't sorted correctly. It is -1 and not 0 because the `i++` at the end of the for loop iterates it back to 0 for the beginning of the array. If it didn't do this, it would only make one pass and it could miss things that are in the wrong order. Read about it here: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/

Bubble sort looks something like this (in this code):

> First pass: [0][3][3][1] the second 3 and 1 are swapped, the iterator
>   is back to the beginning
>
> Second pass: [0][3][1][3] the first 3 and 1 are swapped
>
> Third pass: [0][1][3][3] Nothing needs to be done

This wouldn't have worked if it only made one pass. So, it resets itself so it can make another pass.

(And I should note, as mentioned in the comments, bubble sort is first off inefficient to begin with, and since this implementation resets it each time at the first time it has a problem, it is even more inefficient.)

Answer (score 1):

The `i=-1` is used to restart the for-loop from the beginning in order to traverse the whole structure again. Notice that the `i=-1` is only executed when the algorithm finds something that is unordered.

Answer (score 0):

This construction is used to implement 'bubble sorting' of array passed as an argument. Logic of this code is to check array from the beginning with each 'for' loop that you see in your example. When loop finds that the next element of an array is not sorted, it puts it in the correct order and starts checking array from the beginning. Loop is exited when whole array is sorted. `x = - 1` - the puropse of this assignment is to start next loop from index 0 (as you see, after each loop value of `x` is incremented by one (part `x++` in the 'for' loop), so the next loop starts from index 0)

Answer (score 0):

It restarts the loop.Why?

Because your sort algorithm(Bubble sort) checks numbers one by one and swap them. Then checks from first until all numbers get sorted. Let's see and example:

Our numbers are:

> 25 36 37 25 60

If we don't have that i=-1; 
Then the program would check if 25 is bigger than 36 no.So next Check , if 36 is bigger than 37?No. So next check. If 37 is bigger than 25 ? Yes so swap them.Now we have :

> 25 36 25 37 60

If 37 is bigger than 60? No and Done.

But as you see the array is not sorted. You should recheck and restart loop to beginning every time you swap numbers.

And why -1? You started loop from i=0; and after the loop you have i++. i=-1 and after that i++ means i=0; It means starting loop from beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, this finds 2 neighbours that are out of order and swaps them. 
Then it restarts the loop using `i=-1` since at the end of the loop, `i` will be incremented by 1 giving `i=0`.

It restarts from the beginning of the loop since now `i-1` and `i` might be in the wrong order as well.

This is by far, the least optimal solution, since it runs in O(n^2) time.

PS: As few of the comments are calling this bubble sort, which is false. Bubble sort continues until the end of the array before restarting.

Edit:
This could easily be performed in O(n) time with O(1), or constant, space by finding the min and max value in the array and returning the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this entire function is not an example of good code to study or imitate!

If the side effect of sorting the array is desirable, here is an exact equivalent implementation that will run in `O(n log n)` instead:

```
public static int bigDiff(int[] nums) {
    Arrays.sort(nums);
    return nums[nums.length - 1] - nums[0];
}
```

If the side effect of sorting the array is not needed, then you can return the difference in `O(n)` time with `O(1)` space:

```
public static int bigDiff(int[] nums) {
    int highest = nums[0];
    int lowest = nums[0];
    for (int num : nums) {
        if (num > highest) {
            highest = num;
        }
        if (num < lowest) {
            lowest = num;
        }
    }
    return highest - lowest;
}
```

Note that none of these implementations handle error cases: what if `nums` is `null`, or has zero length, etc.